# How Do I exit a loop and afterwards print Text

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop

I've been trying to simulate somehting like the lottery.
I told java to run the while loop until the variable playCount equals 1000. Here is my code:

```
package problemset.leveltwo;

import java.util.*;
public class PlaySimLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();

    int High = 100;
    int Low = 10;
    int playCount = 0;
    int winCount = 0;
    int loseCount = 0;

    while (playCount > 1000) {
        int yourNumber = random.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        int winningNumber = random.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

        if (yourNumber == winningNumber) {
            winCount = (winCount + 1);
        }

        if (yourNumber != winningNumber) {
            loseCount = (loseCount + 1);
        }

        playCount = (playCount + 1);

        if (playCount == 1000) {
            break;
        }

System.out.println("You Won " + winCount + " Times");
System.out.println("You Lost" + loseCount + " Times");

      }

}

}
```

After I run the program it prints no information or statistics in the console of java eclipse. It says " PlaySimLoop (java application)" followed by a route to where it is saved on my computer.

Help is appreciated!
Tyler

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition is wrong

```
while (playCount > 1000) {
```

Will run while the variable is GREATER than 1000. But it starts at being 0... so the loop will never run. You probably want:

```
while (playCount < 1000) {
```

Which will run while the variable is less than 1000.

Furthermore, this blurb:

```
if (playCount == 1000) {
    break;
}
```

Is unneccessary. The loop condition as defined in this answer will automatically stop after 999. Meaning this condition could never be true if you simply increment the counter by 1 each time as you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! I only used break; because I couldn't exit the loop.

Comment: One more thing. I only want the console to print the stats once. I changed the program and it worked but now the console printed the stats 1000 times. The actual System.out.println("You Won " + winCount + " Times") isn't in the wile loop and same for the loseCount correct?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move the `System.out.println` out of the while loop.

`someNumber = (someNumber + 1)` can be written as `someNumber += 1` or using the postfix increment operator: `someNumber++`. Instead of using another if condition you can use an else block.

```
if (yourNumber == winningNumber) {
    winCount++;
} else {
    loseCount++;
}
```

`loseCount` could also be calculated at the end from `playCount - winCount`.